# A ListView in side an AlertDialog having an EditText field and it had focus but keyboard not getting popped up

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard

[image][image]I have an AlertDialog rendering a multi choose listview, and the listView single row has an editText in it. And the cursor is blinking but no softkeyboard pooping up.

`ArrayList<String> _items_ = new ArrayList<>();
_items_.addAll(Arrays.asList(_items));`

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    assert inflater != null;
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_layout, null);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item);

    final SpinnerDialogAdapter spinnerDialogAdapter = new SpinnerDialogAdapter(context, R.layout.custom_spinner_layout, R.id.tv_attr, _items_, stringHashMap);
    listView.setAdapter(spinnerDialogAdapter);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setDivider(null);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setTitle("Please select");

    builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            HashMap<String, String> attrMapQty = spinnerDialogAdapter.getCheckedItemsQuantities();
            String stringName = spinnerDialogAdapter.getCheckedItemString();

            listener.selectedAttarQuantityMap(attrMapQty, stringName, pos, spAttribute, comment, selectedItem, attributes, rbIsSelected);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can show the keyboard manually:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

textView.requestFocus();
```

Comment: please check the image i just updated in the question above.

Comment: your code did help but the keyboard is coming below, and when there is multiple entries of editText in the listview, the keyboard doesn't even popup also